# I get a segmentation fault instead of an exception

Tags: c++, exception, segmentation-fault, try-catch

In the following code, at the first iteration I get an exception, and at the second one I get a segmentation fault with no error message printed. It seems the exception is not caught:

```
int i = 0;
while(i++ < 10)
{
   try {
      cout << "Iteration: " << i << endl;
      // Code...
      cout << "OK" << endl;
   }
   catch(...)
   {
      cerr << "Error message" << endl;
      continue;
   }
}

Output:
Iteration 1
Error message
Iteration 2
Segmentation fault
```

Is it normal, or there is something really wrong going on?

In case it should be relevant, in that code block I reset a MySQL connection, and the exception is generated when I check if the connection is closed.

Thank's.

---

*Platform:*
Linux - OpenSuse 11.4
C++ - GCC 4.5.1
Intel Xeon

Comment: Segmentation faults are not caught by `try-catch`. You should use a debugger to catch that instead.

Comment: i'm pretty sure it must be in your `// Code...`. Can't spot segfault spots in what you posted...

Comment: I managed to duplicate your output by writing `if (i==1) throw 0; else i = *(int*)0;` but that's not what your `// Code` does, is it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since segfaults are not caused (directly) the the software, but rather by the processor detecting that you are trying to access invalid memory (or access memory in an invalid way - e.g writing to memory that is write-protected, executing memory that isn't supposed to be executed, etc), it is not "catchable" with `try/catch`, which is designed to catch software that throws an exception. They are both called exceptions, but they originate at different levels of the software/hardware of the system.

Technically, you can catch segfaults with a signal handler for `SIGSEGV`. However, as Ivaylo explains, it's is not, typically, allowed to just "try again" if you get a segfault. The signal hander for `SIGSEGV` is allowed to `longjmp` or `exit`, but shouldn't just return.

Read more about signals here:
http://www.alexonlinux.com/signal-handling-in-linux

Typical C++ exceptions (result of `throw`) can be retried without problem (of course, the same exception may be thrown again, of course.

Answer (score 5):

You can not catch segmentation fault like that. This error is usually unrecoverable and is not handled by the usual try-catch. It means something went **very** wrong probably stack corruption or similar. Try using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to detect what causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: Segfaults also happen when dereferencing an invalid pointer (null or otherwise pointing to an unallocated area) which is a quite common error, nothing dramatic like stack corruption.

Answer (score 1):

`catch` clauses catch exceptions that are thrown by `throw` expressions. In standard C++ (and in any sane C++ implementation) they do **not** catch errors detected by the operating system or by the hardware. To do otherwise would make it far too hard to write exception-safe code.