# Why don't visual studio code throw error when handle with null value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc

I have the code below:

```
class A
{
public:
    int *b;
};
int main()
{
    A *a = new A();
    a->b = new int(1);
    cout << *a->b;
    cout << "done";
    return 0;
}
```

I run it and get the expected output `1done` but when I comment the `a->b = new int(1);` It just print nothing. How to make it throw something for me to identify where the error is in my code. My VS Code version is 1.60.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the most important things about variables is initialization.  You are not initializing `b`.  You should probably write a constructor that initializes b to `nullptr` at a minimum.  I believe `int *b = nullptr` would suffice in this case.

Comment: "How to make it throw something for me to identify where the error is in my code." Don't use C++. You might find that a debug build throws for *most* undefined behaviour, but not all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the fault of Visual Studio Code. Your code will have **undefined behavior** (it might throw a segmentation fault, or it might not) if you comment out `a->b = new int(3)` line. See [I get a segmentation fault instead of an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899749/) about how you cannot throw an exception (which VS Code can show) when a segmentation fault is happening.

You could go to the terminal of VS Code and then run:

```
g++ yourfile.cpp
./a.out
```

That showed me a segmentation fault like so:

```
./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: `Your code will throw segmentation fault` not really. It's UB, so anything can happen

Comment: @phuclv you are right...undefined behavior. Thank you.

Comment: @phuclv Yes it throw nothing to me. But how can I get the position of the error to fix if there is more than one ```segmentation fault```  in my code?

Comment: @PhuocNguyen it's the job of the programmer to never leave anything uninitialized and never access uninitialized or out-of-bound memory. If a program behaves unstably or arbitrary then it suspiciously have UB. Always enable compiler warnings and fix them although it may not help you in this case

Comment: @PhuocNguyen write some code, run it. If it runs in an unexpected manner, revert back the code you added. That'll allow you to catch issues. If/when you get familiar with Git version control, testing will become easier.

Comment: @PhuocNguyen would you like any additional information related to your question or has it been satisfactorily answered?

Comment: @zedfoxus thanks I got it

Comment: @PhuocNguyen Thank you. If you have your own answer, can you type it here and mark your own answer as accepted (or mark mine)? Your question is really good and I hope others searching for a similar problem can find this question as solved. If you mark your own answer or an answer as accepted, it'll help others.